# org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext() returns non initialized object when process step is async

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

using wso2bps 3.6.0

i have code like this in our process step:

```java
import org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext;
CarbonContext cctx = CarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext();
String domain = cctx.getTenantDomain();
```

if step marked as `Exclusive` this code returns correct value.

if step marked as `Asynchronous` then i got `domain=null`.

Finally this behavior fails access to other carbon properties and registry.

It seems the problem in this ThreadLocal data holder that does not return initialized holder for my Async thread in `org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder` :

```java
private static ThreadLocal<CarbonContextDataHolder> currentContextHolder = new ThreadLocal(){
    protected CarbonContextDataHolder initialValue(){
      return new CarbonContextDataHolder(null);
    }
};
```

**The questions**

How to get carbon domain and registry in my process step when it Asynchronous?

Maybe there is a way to initialize my thread to allow use of carbon registry?

---

PS: As workaround I use Exclusive step prior to long-running Anync step in my process to evaluate required carbon-dependent properties.

Comment: Do you know the tenant that you wanna access?

Comment: I want to access current tenant. The method getTenantId also returns wrong value -1 instead of -1234